# How to transpose a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, pivot, transpose

i want to change the format of the table that i had. i've heard about the `pivot` statement but don't know how to apply it to my situation.

i thought about rearrange the table once i export it to csv file but it will take time and an extra step.

this is what i have so far

```
+------+------------+-----------+-------+
| name |    date    | breakfast | lunch |
+------+------------+-----------+-------+
| Mike | 21/02/2019 |         1 |     0 |
| Adam | 21/02/2019 |         1 |     0 |
| Liam | 13/05/2019 |         1 |     1 |
+------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

i would like to change the format to

```
+------------+-----------+-------+
|    days    | breakfast | lunch |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| 21/02/2019 |           |       |
| Mike       |         1 |     0 |
| Adam       |         1 |     0 |
| 13/05/2019 |           |       |
| Liam       |         1 |     1 |
+------------+-----------+-------+
```

it does not have to be exactly the same, i just want the export to show the `name` and meals based on `date` 
i tried to use `group by` but i got it wrong, please help

Comment: What about using an online tool? Like this one: http://convertcsv.com/transpose-csv.htm

Comment: i thought about it, and yes, it works but i want explore other ways to solve a problem

Comment: MySQL, unfortunately, doesn't implement a `PIVOT` statement. And, the sort of header / detail formatting presented in your question is usually done by a reporting program, not with pure SQL. You *can* do it in SQL, but it's a notorious pain in the neck to get right.

Comment: what would be a good way to get the my desirable output, given the database is huge and is constantly updating?

Comment: What would be the main purpose of the output? For reporting or for importing? And you do know that once you combined the date and name in a single column, you'll eliminate the possibility of filtering those data by date, right?